# Interfaces with type override C#

Tags: c#, .net, types, interface

I am trying to setup my waypoint system in a more flexible way so i can use derived classes for more customisation but i am stuck with how to set the ability to define the derived type to it.

I have the interface like this:

```
public interface ISegment
{
    IWaypoint WaypointA { get; set; }
    IWaypoint WaypointB { get; set; }
}
```

And my Segment has:

```
public class Segment : ISegment
{
    private Waypoint _waypointA;
    public IWaypoint WaypointA
    {
        get => _waypointA;
        set => _waypointA = value;
    }

    private Waypoint _waypointB;
    public IWaypoint WaypointB
    {
        get => _waypointB;
        set => _waypointB = value;
    }
}
```

Waypoint Class:

```
public class Waypoint : IWaypoint 
{

     public Vector3 Position {get; set;} // from IWaypoint

     //...custom logic ... //
}
```

Where `Waypoint` is my derived class with all my custom logic. But i can't do it this way because it won't convert the `IWaypoint` to the backing field `_waypoint` of type `Waypoint : IWaypoint`.

What is the correct way to set this up so i can apply my own custom waypoint class but still have the rigid contract setup that an interface demands?

Comment: Does `Segment` internally depend on the specific implementation `Waypoint` or does it only depend on its waypoints implementing `IWaypoint`?

Comment: `Segment` only has IWaypoint implementations since otherwise it would force me to only use the specific `Waypoint` class.

Comment: So what exactly is not working? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk the setters in Segment are syntactically an error since it cannot convert IWaypoint to Waypoint.

Comment: Can you change `_waypointA` datatype to `IWaypoint`?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk yes but then i lose all access to any public methods in `Waypoint` such as my custom logic. This is why i am stuck on how to setup the code for such flexibility.

Comment: Either expose your public methods in `IWayPoint` or just use concrete `WayPoint` in Segment. Also, use auto-properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can implement `ISegment` explicitly, i.e.:

```
public class Segment : ISegment
{
    public Waypoint WaypointA { get; set; }

    IWaypoint ISegment.WaypointA
    {
        get => WaypointA;
        set => WaypointA = (Waypoint) value; // throw an exception if value is not of type Waypoint
    }
}

public interface IWaypoint { }

public class Waypoint : IWaypoint { }

public interface ISegment
{
    IWaypoint WaypointA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How come this allows you to convert to `Waypoint` for `value` when the property type is `IWaypoint` ?

Comment: @WDUK, that's not conversion, this is casting. Why it should not?